# SQL replace function

Tags: sql, pervasive

I would like to replace characters within my WHERE statement that have the first character of S,

right now all i have is the following:

```
WHERE i1.CODE = REPLACE(i2.CODE, 'S', 'U')
```

but this would replace all S's with U's. I just wish to replace the S with a U **only when the S is the first character**

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE i1.CODE = REPLACE(LEFT(i2.CODE,1), 'S', 'U') + RIGHT(i2.CODE, LEN(i2.CODE)-1)
```

Comment: I always like using `8000` or `2147483647` instead of `Len` in these situations. It should theoretically use slightly less CPU and it makes for a shorter expression.

Comment: ok thank you , it seems to be running but it is quite slow, but that is ok as this statement will only be done once. Just for testing is there a way to limit an UPDATE statement so that it only runs for a certain amount of row updates so that I can test if it works instead of trying to run it for my entire table (which is 100k + rows) and then find out the result isnt what I wanted and waste a lot of time? thanks

Comment: @seb: `TOP (n)`, as in SQL Server, or `LIMIT n`, as in MySQL/PostgreSQL, or whatever other equivalent Pervasive supports.

Comment: @seb If you're not sure it does what you want, please do it as a `SELECT` statement first before you `UPDATE`, with a "currentvalue" column and a "newvalue" column so you can compare.

Answer (score 2):

```
Where i1.Code = Case
                    When Substring( i2.Code, 1, 1) = 'S' 
                        Then 'U' + Substring( i2.Code, 2, Len( i2.Code ) )
                    Else i2.Code
                    End
```

Another alternative:

```
Where i1.Code = Case
                    When i2.Code Like 'S%'
                        Then 'U' + Substring( i2.Code, 2, Len( i2.Code ) )
                    Else i2.Code
                    End
```

As ErikE suggested, you can also replace `Len(i2.Code)`, with an arbitrarily large static value which might make a small speed improvement.

Comment: Do you think the first substring is better than `LIKE 'S%'`?

Comment: @ErikE - Good question. It may not matter. It would depend on whether the query engine could intelligently parse the Case statement. However, I'll post as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: This is really, really ugly, but I think it works.

```
REPLACE(LEFT(i2.CODE, 1), 'S', 'U') + RIGHT(i2.CODE, LEN(i2.CODE)-1)
```

Comment: I always like using `8000` or `2147483647` instead of `Len` in these situations. It should theoretically use slightly less CPU and it makes for a shorter expression.

Comment: sorry, I am not following... is 8000 the name of a sql string function?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors: No, 8000 was meant as a second parameter of `RIGHT`, instead of `LEN`.

Comment: Well, in your case, yes, the length of the substring to return should be calculated precisely. If you used SUBSTRING, though, you could put 8000 as the length (as in `SUBSTRING(CODE, 2, 8000)`).

Comment: Oops, sorry @therealmitch and @Andriy, I didn't notice it was a `Right()` function... yes, I meant with `Substring`.